# Why Can't I get a Smooth Sine Curve in PSPICE

Tags: audio, simulation, basic, pspice

I am trying to simulate a Volume Control Circuit in PSPice Student Edition. I am unable to see a smooth sine curve at the output. Could you check my circuit. Find the Schematic below

[image]

[image: Sharp curves on Input]
Thanks

Comment: I couldn`t find the circuit, nevertheless: I suppose you have selected not enough data points for displaying the simulation results. Recommendation: Require at least 100 points per period.

Comment: Unless you paste the circuit here, I won't even bother trying, because your "onedrive" file may be gone tomorrow making the answer worthless.

Comment: @pipe I just pasted the circuit. Just see if you can help me out.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Set a minimum time step size of something like 1 microsecond in the transient analysis settings.

If you set it too small it will take too long to do the simulation.

[image]